# Run same function in parallel with different parameters and know which parallel run has ended in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-2.7, multiprocessing

I have an execution function which should be run on more than one device parallelly. And I need to be calling a different function on completing each parallel run. I can't wait for all the parallel call to complete as it takes very different time according to the parameter passed.

```py
    def func1(device, arg1, arg2):
        # do something

    for device in devices:
       # Call func1 with different arguments in parallel
       # If one of the parallel is finished call func2(arg, arg1, arg2) with different arguments.
```

How can I do this in Python?

Comment: Do you already know parameters for calling `func2`? Or these parameters are result of `func1`?

Comment: It can be results also or it can be decided according to knowing which evice has completed the run.

Comment: send to function unique number and return it with result  - or return parameters with result - this way you can recognize process.

Comment: @furas Can you just write a psuedocode for the same. It would be helpful to me. Thank you.

Comment: there is nothing to write - only `result, parameters = function(parameters)` and `def function(parameters): ... return result, parameters`

Comment: BTW: in [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) some functions (`*_async`) accept callback function which they can run after ending process - so you don't have to do it manually. But I'm not sure if it can run callback with arguments or if it can use `lambda` to assign `callback` with arguments.

Answer (score 1):

See this code sample which uses the `future.ThreadPoolExecutor` for parallel execution.

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, Future, as_completed

devices = []


def func1(device, arg1, arg2):
    pass


def do_after_func1(func1_result: Future):
    identifier = func1_result.arg
    result = func1_result.result()
    # do what ever
    pass


device_executors = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=20)
args = []  # can be anything
futures = []
for device in devices:
    tracker = device_executors.submit(func1, *args)
    tracker.arg = "some-identififcation-if-you-need"
    tracker.add_done_callback(do_after_func1)
    futures.append(tracker)
```

You can submit anything to be executed in parallel as a `callable` and the result can be funneled to a call back function `do_after_func1`. You can decide what to be called afterwards here. All this happens in parallel.

You can also make use of the `ProcessPoolExecutor` if you think multiple processes is needed.

You can learn more from the official documentation.